# PHP Append filenames to array

Tags: php, arrays, file, append

I am trying to append filenames to an array in PHP. I have code which reads filenames from a directory "songs" on a server. I simply want each of these filenames to be added to an array. How could I do this?

Here is my PHP.

```
$target = "songs/"; 
$items = array();
if ($handle = opendir($target)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            foreach($song as $entry) {
                $items[] = $entry; 
            }

            //echo $items;
            echo $entry."\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: What isn't working with the code you have? What does $items look like after the while?

Comment: `foreach($song as $entry)` What is `$song`?

Comment: When I echo $items it returns "ArrayArrayArrayArray......" Stuck in loop. @SloanThrasher

Comment: You're using the same variable `$entry` for the filename and in `foreach ($song as $entry)`. So after the loop, `$entry` contains the last element of `$song`, not the filename.

Comment: What does the database code at the top have to do with this?

Comment: Echo it inside print_r **after the while loop**. ```echo "<p>items:<pre>".print_r($items,true)."</pre></p>";```

Comment: Where is $song assigned?

Comment: Thanks. I have it working. @SloanThrasher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the same variable in the `foreach` loop as you're using to hold the filename from `readdir()`. So when you do `$items[] = $entry;` you're adding the iteration variable to the array, not the filename. There doesn't seem to be any reason to add the filename to the array inside the loop, and you should avoid reusing variables like that, it just causes confusion.

```
$items = array();
if ($handle = opendir($target)) {
    while ($entry = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            $items[] = $entry;
            foreach($song as $s) {
                // do something with $s
            }

            //echo $items;
            echo $entry."\n";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: It seems I am still having trouble. I want each $entry to be appended to the array. @Barmar

Comment: This does append each `$entry` to the array, except for `.` and `..`.